# Algorithm used by Google Chrome for string search?

Tags: algorithm, string, search, google-chrome

Does any one know which is the algorithm used by the browser google-chrome for searching strings `[shortcut:CTRL+F]` ? Is it [Boyer-moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched about the algorithm, and it looks like Boyer-moore but I am not sure. They might have created their own algorithm. Remember, this is google :)

Answer (score 2):

> The `Ctrl+F` on chrome uses a search algorithm inspired by [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and [Boyer-Moore-Horspool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Horspool_algorithm)
>
> The implementation is part of the V8 string search package path in the chromium project - [string-search.h](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/strings/string-search.h)

Read more from [source](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-Chrome-search-text-Ctrl-F-on-a-page-so-quickly/answer/Pratik-Mandrekar?ch=10&share=66fbeef5&srid=iB4i).